# Swift iOS -Which viewController lifecycle event to use to send data to Firebase after a view changes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, viewcontroller

I have some information to send to Firebase. The thing is I want to send the data but I also have to pull the data from there first. The data I get is based on the users input.

I'm already making several nested async calls to Firebase. Not only do i have to wait for the calls to finish to make sure the data has been set but I don't want to have the user waiting around unnecessarily when they can leave the scene and the data can be pulled and changed in a background task.

*I was thinking about using a `NSNotification` after the `performSegueWithIdentifier` is triggered. The `observer` for the `notification` would be inside `viewWillDisappear`.*

**Is this safe to do and if not what's the best way to go about it?**

Code:

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(self.uid!)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fetchSomeValueFromFBThenUpdateAndResendAnotherValue), name: "FbFetchAndSend", object: nil)
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    levelTwoRef //send levelTwo data to FB run 1st callback
         scoreRef   //send score data to FB run 2nd callback
            powerRef //send power data to FB run 3rd  callback
               lifeRef //send life data to FB run Last callback for dispatch_async...

                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                      activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                      performSegueWithIdentifier....
                      //Notifier fires after performSegue???
                      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FbFetchAndSend", object: nil)
                  }
 }

func fetchSomeValueFromFBThenUpdateAndResendAnotherValue(){

    let paymentRef = ref.child("paymentNode")
    paymentRef?.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
       (snapshot) in
       if snapshot.exists(){
           if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
           let paymentAmount = dict["paymentAmount"] as? String

           let updatePayment = [String:AnyObject]()
           updatePayment.updateValue(paymentAmount, forKey: "paymentMade")

           let updateRef = self.ref.child("updatedNode")
           updateRef?.updateChildValues(updatePayments)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the observer in viewWillDisappear, So it won't get fired because it won't be present when your segue is performed.

Add the observer in viewDidLoad and it will work.

But if you just want to call fetchSomeValueFromFBThenUpdateAndResendAnotherValue() when the view is disappearing then there is no need for observer.

Simply call the method on viewWillDisappear like this -

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) 
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    fetchSomeValueFromFBThenUpdateAndResendAnotherValue()
}
```